Do we answer 'bad' questions here?
Reading on Meta StackOverflow, the consensus there seems to be that 'bad' (i.e. poorly researched, lazy, duplicate, etc.) questions shouldn't be answered, as this just encourages more questions of the same type (see this answer).
However, I wonder what is, or should be, the norm here. Taking as a case in point, this question ("How to set about constructing Nootropic stack for learning a particular skill") is clearly not what this site is intended for: it's ill informed, it's about self-help, and probably worse, self-experimentation, and it is, for want of a better word, a bad question.
However, I still posted an answer, because:

there were a number of misconceptions shown in the question which I believed should be addressed; and
This information might be beneficial for others (although admittadly I didn't provide the references I should have).

My question is this: Should such questions be responded to, if doing so could increase the knowledge base available on this site, and be of use to others, or should we cut them a wide berth, so as not to encourage them?

We haven't really discussed this, so thanks for the question! However, we have discussed that self-help questions like that should instantly be closed, and thus if done on time, in principle can no longer be answered until improved. :)

Fair point. Should I remove my answer in that case?

I would leave it for now, it's useful to guide this discussion.

A useful question; very poor questions do seem to be taking over CS.SE lately, so perhaps some community cycles should be spent on faster or more effective ways of discouraging or improving bad questions (or encouraging good ones).

I don't have time today to write a full answer, but basically my advice for what to do when seeing a bad question is to (in this priority order) 1. Flag or vote to close, 2. Edit to improve, 3. Comment asking for edits, 4. Answer

I posted some related thoughts here.

I have minimum rep and so have little "right" to respond here. But I do like and care about cognitive sciences and was excited to see that there was a SE site for it.
On English Language and Usage, the site is what I consider appropriately moderated. Questions showing no research are down voted and bad questions closed either by the community or the mods. On that site, even when I close vote, I still usually provide an answer (in comments), because, well, it's easy.
On this site, answers are not easy; they require an investment of time.
If people are willing to answer poor questions, I don't believe they should be punished for it, however, I think bad answers should be down voted.
